# Jinja2 template.render(..) raises UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, encoding, jinja2, python-unicode

I'm trying to generate XML file based on template I created.
This template is in `windows-1250` - the first line has to be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1250"?>
```

The problem is that when I try to render the template, it returns:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9e in position
>   135: invalid start byte

This is the main code:

```
THIS_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
def render(filename, context):
    env = jinja2.Environment(
        loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(THIS_DIR)
    )
    template = env.get_template(filename) 
    return template.render(context) # THIS RAISES THE ERROR
```

I've tried to add empty context ({}), which didn't helped.

Do you know where is the problem?

Comment: The 135th character in your string-to-decode is non-ascii. The best I could do for you is tell you to manually fix it, which is probably of no help. But I hope this does help you zoom in to the issue. For instance `'weird character \x96'.decode('windows-1252')
u'weird character \u2013'` while decoding with `'weird character \x96'.decode('utf-8')` will return similar error

Comment: I'm parsing lot of PDF's. I find out that the problem is caused because sometimes there are russian names. This is a new error: character maps to <undefined>.  Everything except russian is ok. Is there some way to detect this and prevent rendering?

Comment: the ugly way is to use a try ... except block while logging the Exception caught..

Comment: If the template is saved in some other encoding than UTF-8 you have to tell that to the `FileSystemLoader` by passing the `encoding` argument.